Roll a die in 3D
Simulate a roll of a fair die, and output the result in this ascii-art form:
    .-----------.
   / o       o /|
  /           /o|
 / o       o /  |
:-----------:o o|
| o       o |   |
|           |o o:
|     o     |  /
|           |o/
| o       o |/
'-----------'

Details
The outline of the die (i.e. the non-o characters) should be exactly as shown (with this orientation).  The three faces should show the pip-patterns resulting from a random roll, in the manner shown.
You must simulate one fixed physical die.  It must have faces 1...6 with opposite faces summing to 7.
You can choose whether the arrangement is left or right handed (i.e. whether 1-2-3 go clockwise or anticlockwise around their corner), and you can choose the orientations of the 2, 3 and 6 pip-patterns on their faces.  For example, you might choose that the 6 face has its two lines of three pips next to the 3 and 4 faces.  However, once these choices are made they must be used consistently, in the sense that the physical die cannot change its makeup.  It just rotates randomly.
Thus, once the above choices are made, there should be exactly 24 possible outputs (8 choices for the sticking out corner * 3 rotations), and the program should output one of them chosen uniformly at random (as approximated by any reasonable PRNG).
The pip-patterns are as follows (with - for spaces for clarity).  Each should be transformed by the appropriate affine map to fit on the face as in the example above.
---  ---  o--  o-o  o-o  ooo
-o-  o-o  -o-  ---  -o-  ---
---  ---  --o  o-o  o-o  ooo

Note: As has been pointed out, this choice of 2-pip pattern might be less common in real dice, but in the interests of fairness I'll insist on sticking to these patterns.
To make it completely explicit, each number's pips are a subset of
ooo
ooo
ooo

and here is what the die would look like with all 9 pips on every face:
    .-----------.
   / o   o   o /|
  / o   o   o /o|
 / o   o   o /o |
:-----------:o o|
| o   o   o | o |
|           |o o:
| o   o   o | o/
|           |o/
| o   o   o |/
'-----------'

The output can be printed, or output as a string with newlines or a sequence of lines.  Trailing spaces and up to one trailing blank line are allowed.
This is code-golf so shortest program in each language wins.

I don't think I've ever seen a die where the 2 looks like that and not diagonal, interesting

To clarify what the appropriate affine map is/in the name of self-containedness, could you also provide an example cube where all faces show, say, the 3 pattern superimposed on the bottom half of the 6 pattern?

@RubenVerg Hm - hadn't noticed this.  An image search seems to show plenty of both but possibly more diagonals.  However, I'll leave the challenge as it is!

@UnrelatedString: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/XwEI9HQRQI8LKKCvkA8kIVi/hgtNIB8ogiqgUMNlhWSGVb4CUE0NkhIQGySCADVANVboavTRlOijKtDnUkeyRf3/fwA

@Unrelated String Fair point - I've added an all-9s picture

@RubenVerg Good catch. I wish I had noticed that weird "2" (or your comment) before writing my answer. :-/

It turns out that I sandboxed something very similar: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8197/17602

@Neil 8 years ago!

Allowing 3 as ⋯ rather than ⋱ may enable some creation as x + (7-x) would be 工 shape

Similar challenge, without dots.

Is this intended to prohibit languages with no source of randomness?  May we accept an input to determine the orientation instead?

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  538   478   459   441   440  438 bytes
-60 bytes by compressing some strings of characters in the die string.
-18 bytes by emanresu A.
-1 more byte by reducing 2*(c>3) to c//4*2.
-18 bytes by using not-quite-bytestrings-but-close-enough.
-1 byte by eliminating the need for the %12.
-2 bytes by using actual bytestrings and reemploying the %12.
from random import*
R=randrange
S=str.replace
P=lambda s:f'{ord("(TŅŕŭ‚đŅŕǇ"[n[s]%12]):09b}'.translate(' o'*50)
c=R(8)
n=[3,*b''[c%4:][:2],2+c%2*6][::1-c//4*2]
for _ in[0]*R(3):n[1:]=[n[3]+6,n[1]+6,n[2]]
print(((S(S(S("""    .B.
   /A/|
  /A/}{|
 /A/}{ |
:B:}{ }{|
|A| }{ |
C }{:
|A| }{/
C/
|A|/
'B'""",'A',' %s   %s   %s '),'B','-'*11),'C','|'+' '*11+'|}{')%(*P(3)+P(1),))[::-1].format(*(a:=P(2))[6:]+a[3:6]+a[:3]))[::-1])

I've been banging my head against this problem for about 2 hours now (new record!). Thankfully, the byte count has gone down 100 bytes from the original submission.
...Is that a good thing?
Try it online!

460 with some rearrangements

Charcoal, 146 144 bytes
≔⪪⪪”{∨8⬤⪫η÷﹪H⁵]”³¦³υＦ⪪⁺⁺×‽²⮌⭆⁶ι×⊗‽³⭆⁶⊕ι×‽⁴034215⁶ＵＭυＥ³⮌⭆§υ§ιλ§ξμ¹¹Ｐ↗⁴↓:↓⁵↗'↗³↑:↑⁵←.←¹¹↙.↙³↓:↓⁵:¹¹Ｊ²±¹Ｆ§υ⁰«Ｐ↗ιＭ⁴→»Ｊ¹¦¹Ｅ§υ²⟦⪫ι   ⟧Ｊ¹⁴±²Ｆ§υ⁴«Ｐ↓⪫ι ↙

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔⪪⪪”...”³¦³υ

Split a compressed string into six die faces.
Ｆ⪪⁺⁺×‽²⮌⭆⁶ι×⊗‽³⭆⁶⊕ι×‽⁴034215⁶

Create a series of permutations, consisting of a ½ chance of rotating the die so that the 123 and 546 faces switch places (this is equivalent to three 90° rotations), a ⅓ chance each of rotating the die around the 123-456 long axis by multiples of 120° (which is achieved by repeating a permutation to make the face rotations cancel out), and a ¼ chance each of rotating the die around the top-bottom axis by multiples of 90° (the top and bottom faces also have to be rotated in place, of course). For each permutation...
ＵＭυＥ³⮌⭆§υ§ιλ§ξμ

... apply the permutation, rotating each face for each permutation.
¹¹Ｐ↗⁴↓:↓⁵↗'↗³↑:↑⁵←.←¹¹↙.↙³↓:↓⁵:¹¹

Draw the outline of the die.
Ｊ²±¹Ｆ§υ⁰«Ｐ↗ιＭ⁴→»

Draw the top face.
Ｊ¹¦¹Ｅ§υ²⟦⪫ι   ⟧

Draw the front face.
Ｊ¹⁴±²Ｆ§υ⁴«Ｐ↓⪫ι ↙

Draw the right-hand face.

JavaScript (Node.js), 315 262 bytes
_=>`G .0.
G/1 3 2/|
  /F 4 F/c|
 /2 3 1/d |
:0:b a|
|7 5 6|E|
|GGG  |a b:
|8 9 8| d/
|GGG  |c/
|6 5 7|/
'0'`.replace(/\w/g,c=>c<1?'-----------':(u=c<{}?' ':'')+' o'[1&R>>('0xf'+c-5*e)%15]+u,R=[8724,18966,6864,1232,7218,6414,14998,6390][e=Math.random()*24|0,e%8])

Try it online!
Assume Arnauld's solution is correct as I geneated using its output

@JonathanAllan Cuzof table need be even. Should get fixed

05AB1E, 165 bytes
•1p6¼ujθ²
Ƶ@TV“α½[ÿ™ÆÅ´?µ¼…ǝÆ2.˜ã™Ā"ê7‰Ć₂1ƵcÕ н5Å₅ð¨ôÚ•" 4|
130/:2'."ÅвJ2'-11×:4ð3×:Ž£F0š0δšTΩiR}3LΩFÀÀ}4LΩFDŽBñS©èÁ®ǝεć4LNå+š]ε`•ʒ\RN]–ä•„o Åв3ô3ôsèsFøí]Ƶ2S©è€˜®s.;

Inspired by @Neil's Charcoal answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Try it online.
Explanation:
Step 1: Create the ASCII-art die, with placeholders for the nine positions of the random values:
•1p6¼ujθ²\nƵ@TV“α½[ÿ™ÆÅ´?µ¼…ǝÆ2.˜ã™Ā"ê7‰Ć₂1ƵcÕ н5Å₅ð¨ôÚ•
                      "# Push compressed integer 165694505690730716563168121971474439450718220748920420519623075258410088668853618104539042325788146223319708232484170071664982
" 4|\n130/:2'."Åв      # Convert the large integer to base-" 4|\n130/:2'.",
                       # aka, convert it to base-12, and index into this string
                 J     # Join all characters together
2'-11×:               '# Replace all "2"s with a string consisting of 11 "-"s
4ð3×:                  # Replace all "4"s with a string consisting of 3 spaces

Try just step 1 online.
Step 2a: Create the default representation of the die:
Ž£F                    # Push compressed integer 41325
   0š                  # Convert it to a list of digits, and prepend a 0
      δ                # Map over each digit:
     0 š               #  Pair it with a leading 0

The leading 0s are the rotation-state, indicating how many times we'll have to rotate the face in step 3. The values [0,5] are the indices of the die-faces [1,6].
Try just step 2a online.
Step 2b,c,d: Just like @Neil's Charcoal answer, \$\frac{1}{2}\$ chance of inverting the die (aka reversing the representation of the die); then \$\frac{1}{3}\$ chance of rotating the die 120 degrees around a corner (aka rotating the representation of the dice twice counterclockwise); and then \$\frac{1}{4}\$ chance of rotating the die 90 degrees around a face (aka rotating the representation of the die at the 0-based indices 3→0→4→5→3, and simultaneously increasing the rotation-state at the 0-based indices 1,2,3,4 each once clockwise):
T                      # Push 10
 Ω                     # Pop and push a random digit of it
  i                    # If it's 1:
   R                   #  Reverse the list
  }                    # Close the if-statement

3L                     # Push list [1,2,3]
  Ω                    # Pop and push a random digit of it
   F                   # Loop that many times:
    ÀÀ                 #  Rotate the list twice counter-clockwise
   }                   # Close the loop

4LΩF                   # Similar again, looping randomly [1,2,3,4] amount of times:
    D                  #  Duplicate the current list
     ŽBñ               #  Push compressed integer 3045
        S              #  Convert it to a list of digits: [3,0,4,5]
         ©             #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
          è            #  Get the current value-states at those 0-based indices
           Á           #  Rotate them once clockwise
            ®          #  Push indices [3,0,4,5] again
             ǝ         #  Insert the rotated value-states back into the list at those indices
    ε                  #  Map over each value-state pair:
     ć                 #   Extract head (the current rotation-state)
      4L               #   Push list [1,2,3,4]
        Nå             #   Check if the current 0-based map-index is in this list
                       #   (1 if the index is 1/2/3/4; 0 if the index is 0/5)
          +            #   Add that check to the rotation-state
           š           #   And prepend it back to the pair
   ]                   # Close both the inner map and outer loop

Try just step 2 online.
Step 3: Convert this representation of the die to actual die-values of spaces and "o":
ε                      # Map over each value-state:
 `                     #  Pop and push both values separated to the stack
  •ʒ\RN]–ä•            #  Push compressed integer 17448688417330322
           „o Åв       #  Convert it to base-"o "
                3ô     #  Split it into triplets
                  3ô   #  And then split this list of triplets into 3x3 blocks
                    sè #  Index the current face-index into this list of 3x3 blocks
  sF                   #  Loop the rotation-state amount of times:
    øí                 #   Rotate the 3x3 block once clockwise:
    ø                  #    Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     í                 #    Reverse each inner row
]                      # Close the inner loop and outer map

Try just steps 2 and 3 online.
Step 4: Replace the placeholder digits in the ASCII-art die of step 1 with these random and correctly oriented/rotated die-faces:
Ƶ2                     # Push random integer 103
  S                    # Convert it to a list of digits: [1,0,3]
   ©                   # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
    è                  # Get the die-faces at those 0-based indices
     €˜                # Flatten each 3x3 block to a list of 9 characters
       ®               # Push the digits [1,0,3] again
        s.;            # Replace every "1", "0", and "3" one by one with its 9 face-characters in the ASCII-art die string
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

See this 05AB1E tip of mine to understand how the base of the ASCII-art is generated.
See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to compress large integers?) to understand why •1p6¼ujθ²\nƵ@TV“α½[ÿ™ÆÅ´?µ¼…ǝÆ2.˜ã™Ā"ê7‰Ć₂1ƵcÕ н5Å₅ð¨ôÚ• is 165694505690730716563168121971474439450718220748920420519623075258410088668853618104539042325788146223319708232484170071664982; ŽBñ is 3045; and •ʒ\RN]–ä• is 17448688417330322.

In case it makes any difference, there are of course three different axes for the last rotation; I just chose that rotation that with the 103 list would minimise the number of reorientations, since Charcoal has no Zip operation. With a different string you can make all (although second operation is double À so it cancels out) operations reorient all six faces, although this still requires two of the final faces to be reoriented for output. If I did this in Charcoal I wouldn't be able to use my ¶ to save three bytes but maybe if I used your trick of delaying the reorientations... hmm...

Well, not quite the same, but I managed to save 2 bytes from my answer by collecting my permutations up and processing them with reorientations in one go.

@Neil Nice save by combining your random loops in your answer. And I think I can indeed save some bytes on my answer here and there. Like maybe starting with a different default state instead of 152436, or indeed using different faces than those at indices 1,0,3, but none of those improvements to the algorithm itself are fairly straight-forward, and rn a bit too much trouble for the maybe <3 bytes save.  So I'll probably keep it as is for now.

JavaScript (ES6), 376 bytes
-2 thanks to @l4m2
_=>[..._+""].reduce((p,_,c)=>(q=p.split(c)).join(q.pop(n=parseInt("0d6s2o0vn9uo33hkf42s3hnk3wawr4298ves0bjvf4378gw42t9h5u068so81efteq35ft0o33ndze301xqi141wy20bmphm01n4162ogucq467q222s0j6y33937y0lfd5m0dfc0e32bgey".substr((Math.random()*24|0)*6,6),36))),`0.2.
61|
  1o|
 1o |
:2:o3|43 |53:43/5/4/
'2'836o6o 7-----0  5
|660 |o4
|8|3 o277-1/8/06 `).replace(/o/g,c=>(n/=2)&1?c:" ")

Try it online!

Can u -1 by _=>[..._+""].reduce((p,_,c)=>?
